# Destinationsource.getQueues doesn't return the right amount of queues with SSL-Connection

Tags: java, ssl, activemq-classic

I want to know the number of queues on my ActiveMQ and I have this Code, which works with my local installation of ActiveMQ:

```
ActiveMQSslConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQSslConnectionFactory(url);
//connectionFactory.setTrustStore("truststore.ts");
//connectionFactory.setTrustStorePassword("password");

ActiveMQConnection connection = (ActiveMQConnection) connectionFactory.createConnection();
connection.start();

DestinationSource destinationQueues = connection.getDestinationSource();        
Set<ActiveMQQueue> queues = destinationQueues.getQueues();  

System.out.println(queues.size());
```

But when I'm using it on our ActiveMQ on the server (with the truststore) it will return zero queues. I know that the connection works because I can consume messages from one exact queue. I already tried tips from other threads like `sleep` but it still won't work.

Is it maybe because of the SSL Connection, do I have to change something in this case? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem. It's a setting of the ActiveMQ which is found in the activemq.xml. The part `advisorySupport="false"` caused the problem. After commenting this setting out, the query returns the true amount of queues.

Answer (score 0):

The Destination Source bits make no guarantee of timely return of the full set of Queues etc.  It could be you have configured the SSL connector on the broker differently or it could just be that due to the much slower throughput of SSL on JDK implementations the data hasn't arrived.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So is there any possibility that would work with SSL, other than Destination Source? Or does the broker has to be configured differently in this case?